# What standard MCPH3 package belong to?

Tags: diodes

When i go through a diode datasheet, i saw that the device's package is MCPH3 and bellow that i found SC-70 (JEITA), SOT-323 (JEDEC). Can anyone help me to find out the details about MCPH3. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The MCPH3 package nomenclature is an OnSemi name for the SC-70 package standard:

[image: Package]

The [package specification document](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/419AQ.PDF) provides the above diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Given that *every* reference to MCPH3 as a semiconductor package is in reference to an ON Semiconductor device, I am going to say that the designation is *not* controlled by any standards body and is instead only used by ON Semiconductor.

Comment: ++++++++++++++1